# What is QPI Isochronous Mode in x86 platforms?

Tags: central-processing-unit, x86

I'm just wondering what exactly QPI Isochronous mode stands for? On some server motherboards, specially Supermicro ones there's one option that comes disabled by default under QPI General Configuration: Isoc Mode.

Doing some homework and searching the web about some information leads to vastly different opinions and non-scientific data of what it would effective implements.

What Isochronous Mode implements and when should I enable it?